# unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions."

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-rekognition

I have a Lambda function that scans for text and is triggered by an S3 bucket. I get this error when trying to upload a photo directly into s3 bucket using browser

> Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region, and/or access permissions

However, if I hardcode the key (e.g., image01.jpg) which is in my bucket, there are no errors.

```py
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
#   Get bucket and file name 
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    location  = key[:17]
    s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
    client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='us-east-1')
    response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object': 
    {'Bucket':'myarrowbucket','Name':key}})
    detectedText = response['TextDetections']
```

I am confused as it was working a few weeks ago but now i am getting that error

Comment: Have your credentials expired? Have you changed your IAM permissions? Which line is specifically erroring? What do you mean by 'S3 panel'? The AWS Console?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary error had nothing to do with credentials or IAM (using educate account so couldnt change anyways) . sorry i meant s3 bucket using browser , have updated

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

I have seen this question answered many times and i tried every solution , the one which worked for me was 'key' name . i was getting the metadata error when the filename contained special characters e.g - or _ but when i changed the names of the files uploaded it works . Hope this answer helps someone.

Comment: *the one which worked for me* -- If that was a Stack Overflow answer, please mark your own question as a duplicate of the other question.